# Insert into Access Database on button click

Tags: c#, ms-access, oledb

i'm still new in c# programing ,is any one can help me to solve this error coming when i try to add a data in database but error comes after this line command.ExecuteNonQuery();

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  string constr = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Users\aberto\Documents\esimar_db.accdb;Persist Security Info=False;";
  string cmdstr = "insert into employee(employee_name, location,connection,depanse,caisse)values(@employee_name,@location,@connection,@depanse,@caisse)";

  OleDbConnection connect = new OleDbConnection(constr);
  OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand(cmdstr, connect);
  connect.Open();
  command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@employee_name", textBox1.Text);
  command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@location", comboBox1.Text);
  command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@connection", textBox2.Text);
  command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@depanse", textBox3.Text);
  command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@printing", textBox4.Text);
  command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@caisse", textBox5.Text);
  command.ExecuteNonQuery();
  MessageBox.Show( "Record saved successfully");

  connect.Close();
}
```

Comment: The exact error message will greatly help you finding the source of it.

Answer (score 1):

`CONNECTION` is [reserved word](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Access-2007-reserved-words-and-symbols-e33eb3a9-8baa-4335-9f57-da237c63eabe?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US#__toc272229040) in Access SQL so you have to enclose it in square brackets if it is to be used as a column (or table) name:

```csharp
string cmdstr = 
        "insert into employee(employee_name, location, [connection], depanse, caisse) values (@employee_name, @location, @connection, @depanse, @caisse)";
```

Also, be aware that your CommandText only has five (5) parameters in it, but you have six (6) `Parameters.AddWithValue` statements. OleDb **ignores** parameter names and only pays attention to the order in which the parameters are declared, so only the first five (5) of those statements will have any effect.